# Should I have both WSL version Visual Studio Code and Windows version Visual Studio Code to develop in WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I am planning to learn development in WSL and will develop some personal projects on WSL.
but I already have visual studio code in my Windows 10.
Should I install Ubuntu version Visual Studio Code to develop or windows version is enough? 
Or should I remove windows VSC? 
I am really newbie in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in linux set up visual studios for wsl with snap https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please transcript at least some of the documentation from the site linked to your answer? If the link every gets deleted or changed, it will no longer be helpful.